# Emulator Fails to Run my App

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

In the eclipse/android AVD, I get the message "Unfortunately,  has stopped".

I have checked other questions about this, but I'm assuming it is specific to my application.  I'm not sure where the error is as the code shows no problems or errors in the code.  I'm wondering if it could be a problem with the way I set up my emulator, or specific problems in my code.

Here are the sections for my code:

activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_schedule"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_facebook"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_facebook"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:src="@drawable/schedule"
    android:background="@null" 
    android:contentDescription="@string/none"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_cfrc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_schedule"
    android:layout_marginLeft="73dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_schedule"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/website"
    android:contentDescription="@string/none"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_twitter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_cfrc"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/twitter"
    android:contentDescription="@string/none"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_facebook"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_twitter"
    android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/facebook"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/none"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main_Activity.java:

```
    package com.example.cfrcradio;
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {    
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_twitter);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.twitter.com/CFRC"));
                startActivity(myWebLink); 

        } 
    });


    Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_facebook);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com/cfrc.kingston
fref=ts"));
                startActivity(myWebLink);
        }
    });

    Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cfrc);
    btn3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.cfrc.ca/blog/"));
                startActivity(myWebLink);
        }
    });

    Button btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_schedule);
    btn4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.cfrc.ca/blog/programming/schedule"));
                startActivity(myWebLink);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.cfrcradio"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.cfrcradio.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Please help!!

Comment: post your logcat output please

Answer (score 0):

[`Button`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)s and [`ImageButton`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)s are not the same. `ImageButton` actually extends from `ImageView` and **not** `Button`.

A `ClassCastException` should be thrown with your current implementation.

In your case, you will need to change all occurences of `Button`, so it is `ImageButton`. For example

```
Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_twitter);
```

should be

```
ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_twitter);
```

Comment: @ShannonNeville Since my answer solved your issue, you should accept my answer by clicking the hollowed out checkmark so it turns green.